# Averageifs in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need help with a formula that will provide answers for the yellow shaded cells below.  I think it's an average ifs function.  I keep getting DIV/0

In the example below, I'm trying to get the average test score for Techs and Apprentices by state:

```
       A          B           C         D   
1    Name       Title       Location   Test score
2    Joe        Tech          NY       76%
3    Mary       Apprentice    NY       88%
4    Steve      Tech          NJ       63%
5    Harry      Installer     MA       98%
6    Manfred    Tech          IA       77%
7    Sam        Installer     NY       84%
8    Steve      Apprentice    CT       85%
9    Paul       Apprentice    CT       86%
10   Jenn       Installer     IA       88%
```

Desired result:

```
Average test score for Techs and Apprentices by state:              

    NY      ?   
    NJ      ?   
    MA      ?   
    IA      ?   
    CT      ?
```

Comment: (1) Obviously, there are no "yellow shaded cells".  (2) You "keep getting `DIV/0`"?  That suggests that you have tried something.  What have you tried?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a pivot table without hurting any formulas.

Click a cell in the data table, then Insert > Pivot Table. Drag the Location into the Rows area and the Test Score into the values area. Right click the Test Score field in the values area, change the Value Field Settings to Average. The screenshot shows the pivot table in columns F and G.

Or, manually create a list of locations and use a formula. In the following screenshot, the values in column F are used with this formula starting in cell H3 and copied down:

```
=AVERAGEIF($C$2:$C$10,F3,$D$2:$D$10)
```

[image]